# WP_Query categories tree

Tags: wordpress

I have a loop that shows images from specific category.

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 10,   
'post_status' => 'inherit', 
'post_type'=> 'attachment',
'cat' => 777
); 

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I'm looking to get posts in that category both in categories that are descendants of that category.Thanks

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking. Are you looking to get posts, not just in that category, but in categories that are descendants of that category?

Comment: I'm looking to get posts in that category both in categories that are descendants of that category.

Comment: Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. **Questions should include details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_term_children()`, to first get the descendants of that category. You can then pass that list of term ids in the query arguments, under the `category__in` key:

```
$category_id = 777;
$term_ids = get_term_children($category_id, 'category');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,   
    'post_status' => 'inherit', 
    'post_type'=> 'attachment',
    'category__in' => array($category_id) + $term_ids
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```